# PHP/MySQL newbie Got Packets out of order

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I'm trying to follow this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

I'm about half way down the page Verifying PHP/MySQL functionality and am stuck.

I just set up MAMP for the first time.
I have two files in my MAMP htdocs directory

index.php

```
<?php
    echo "Hello, PHP!";
?>
```

promocodes.php

```
<?php

class RedeemAPI {
    private $db;

    // Constructor - open DB connection
    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'promos');
        $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
    }

    // Destructor - close DB connection
    function __destruct() {
        $this->db->close();
    }

    // Main method to redeem a code
    function redeem() {
        // Print all codes in database
        echo "Hello, PHP!";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id, code, unlock_code, uses_remaining FROM rw_promo_code');
        echo "Hello, PHP!";
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $code, $unlock_code, $uses_remaining);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo "$code has $uses_remaining uses remaining!";
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
}

?>
```

when I go to `http://localhost:8888/index.php` I get

> "Hello, PHP!";

when I go to `http://localhost:8889/index.php` I get the following gibberish

> H���
>   5.5.9�G���}Se"tHIr�ÿ÷�€����������(ja&7"BfZoB<�mysql_native_password!��ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order

when I go to `http://localhost:8888/promocodes.php` I get

> 

when I go to `http://localhost:8889/promocodes.php` I get the following gibberish

> H���
>   5.5.9�H���x%J'"s@#�ÿ÷�€����������-YX0#_89T|50�mysql_native_password!��ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order

Comment: It seems maybe you also have an encoding issue, gzipped response or perhaps your your outputting the wrong content headers.

Comment: Found the problem, when I copied in the new RedeemAPI class I deleted the code that actually uses the class.  
`// This is the first thing that gets called when this page is loaded  
// Creates a new instance of the RedeemAPI class and calls the redeem method  
$api = new RedeemAPI;  
$api->redeem();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, when I copied in the new RedeemAPI class I deleted the code that actually uses the class.

```
// This is the first thing that gets called when this page is loaded
// Creates a new instance of the RedeemAPI class and calls the redeem method
$api = new RedeemAPI;
$api->redeem();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have `old_password=1` in your `my.cnf` file you might try setting it to `0` and resetting your password.

Answer (score 0):

As the stackoverflow's policy does not allow me to enclose too many links, please take ADDR for localhost

1. You are not supposed to call **ADDR:8888/index.php** but to put **index.php** file inside promos folder and call **ADDR:8888/promos** (in your case this may be **index.php** file inside promocodes folder so the address would be **ADDR:8888/promocodes**)
2. When you go which 8889 port number you try to hit MySQL directly which you are not supposed to be doing as well. Try using port 8888 and this command:

   ```
    curl -F "rw_app_id=1" -F "code=test" -F "device_id=test2" ADDR:8888/promos/
   ```

   or

   ```
    curl -F "rw_app_id=1" -F "code=test" -F "device_id=test2" ADDR:8888/promocodes
   ```

(assuming you do have **index.php** inside promocodes folder)
 3. Remember that when you try to hit the server with you web browser's navigation bar you do send a GET type request. If you need an alternative to curl, try using some web browser's plugin like "Poster" (dedicated for FireFox).

Answer (score 0):

> [���
>   5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1����UW47HvY�ÿ÷�ÿ����������nfm@*g}

I am not sure what is fabric in MySQL.  I've never seen this before, but this page seems to come from:

> /etc/mysql/fabric.cfg

Modify the configuration file or remove any links to the main Apache configuration.