# Wamp gets packets out of order after Windows restart

Tags: php, windows, wamp

Whenever I try to serve project from VS Code, after Windows restart I get message like this:

```
J���
8.0.29����MNguts]�ےےے�ےك����������uE&)c^L:{�caching_sha2_password�!��ے„#08S01Got packets out of order
```

After I reinstall Wamp everything works, until I restart Windows.

Comment: Search [results here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053613/apache-mysql-packets-out-of-order-on-3306), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935847/php-mysql-newbie-got-packets-out-of-order) from part of your error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was port 3000 being taken by TCP.

You should open CMD as an administrator and follow up to solve this error.

```
netstat -ano | findstr :<PORT>
```

Port, in my case, was 3000

and then

```
taskkill /PID <PID> /F
```

After that, reload the server and enjoy!